# Optimize the execution speed and improve the readability of code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

How can I optimize the speed and improve readability for the following piece of code?

```
for j in range(len(Relevant_data)):
    for x in ['A', 'BB', 'BV', 'Cy', 'R','T']:
      if Relevant_data['Type'].iloc[j]==x:
           if Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]>=np.asscalar(t.loc[x,0.0].values) and Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]<np.asscalar(t.loc[x,0.25].values):
                Relevant_data['Bin'].iloc[j]="{} of {}".format("Bin1",x)
            elif Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]>=np.asscalar(t.loc[x,0.25].values) and Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]<np.asscalar(t.loc[x,0.50].values):
                Relevant_data['Bin'].iloc[j]="{} of {}".format("Bin2",x)
            elif Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]>=np.asscalar(t.loc[x,0.50].values) and Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]<np.asscalar(t.loc[x,0.75].values):
                Relevant_data['Bin'].iloc[j]="{} of {}".format("Bin3",x)
            elif Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]>=np.asscalar(t.loc[x,0.75].values) and Relevant_data['Amount'].iloc[j]<=np.asscalar(t.loc[x,1.00].values):
                Relevant_data['Bin'].iloc[j]="{} of {}".format("Bin4",x)
```

Comment: I don't think converting it to a lambda function will be a good idea. You should prioritize writing readable code.

Comment: lambda functions are only syntactic sugar – do you mean `np.,vectorize`?

Comment: I want to bring down the execution time. Any help in that direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to increase the readability and improve the execution time of my code.

```
def analyze(Amount_R,Type_R): 
    if np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,0.0].values)<=Amount_R<np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,0.25].values):
        return "{} of {}".format("Bin1",Type_R)  
    if np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,0.25].values)<=Amount_R<np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,0.50].values):
        return "{} of {}".format("Bin2",Type_R) 
    if np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,0.50].values)<=Amount_R<np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,0.75].values):
        return "{} of {}".format("Bin3",Type_R)  
    if np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,0.75].values)<=Amount_R<=np.asscalar(t.loc[Type_R,1.00].values):
        return "{} of {}".format("Bin4",Type_R) 
Relevant_data_Retailers['Bin']=np.vectorize(analyze)(Relevant_data_Retailers['Transaction_Amount'],Relevant_data_Retailers['Transaction_Type'])
```